# Groovy Support for Springsource Tool Suite

Tags: groovy, plugins, spring-tool-suite, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

What is the best support for groovy in Eclipse. Are there any plugins you could recommend. I tried Greclipse Plugin, but it seems not full compatible with STS 3.9.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it seemed I took an old link of Greclipse. STS3.9.2 seems to be compatible with http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.8/